# AJAX form to create new post (WordPress)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to send form data via AJAX to a php script that will create a new post in wordpress. The code I have seems like it should work, but for some reason nothing is happening.

The form is pretty huge, but the basic info I'm trying to get working now is:

```
<form action="/create-event" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="event-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="userID" id="userID" value="<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>" />

    <fieldset>
        <label for="event-name">Event Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="event-name" name="event-name" value="" required />
    </fieldset> 

    <input type="text" id="event-main-cat" name="event-main-cat" class="main-cat" required />
    <input type="text" id="sub-cat" name="sub-cat" class="sub-category-input" value="" />

</form>
```

AJAX:

```
(function( $ ){
$( document ).ready(function() {


$('input[type=button]').on('click', function() {

    if( $('.event-form').valid() ) {

        var loadUrl = '/auto-save-post.php';

        // ajax the results!
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: $('.event-form').serialize(),
            url: templateDir + loadUrl, // templateDir is declared in the footer
            success: function(result) {
                console.log('data sent!');
                console.log('sent to: ' + templateDir + loadUrl );
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });


    }

});


});
})( jQuery );
```

PHP:

```
$data = $_POST['serialize'];

    // set basic event info
    $new_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'post_author' => $data['userID'],
        'post_title' => $data['event-name'],
        'post_date' => Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'tax_input' => array( 
            'main-cat' => $data['event-main-cat'],
            'sub-cat' => $data['sub-cat']
        )
    );

    // create the draft event
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

EDIT 
As requested, the information from the Network tab:

**Headers:**

```
Remote Address: 168.249.133.103:80
Request URL:http://website.co.uk/wp-content/themes/woa-2014/auto-save-post.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1616
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:wp-settings-time-3=1401887703; wp-settings-time-5=1402046083; wp-settings-1=libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26urlbutton%3Dfile; wp-settings-time-1=1402995301; G_USERSTATE_H4=113882842213089035920=1; PHPSESSID=4e2b3d299649e1410fe8501b6a25e0b1; linkedin_oauth_77r7rxe672z4s8_crc=null; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_42509f9da25d0091a8295263478f1ff8=admin%7C1720385704%7Cd6b43843769a67a8e0746f7f784786d3; __atuvc=108%7C24%2C391%7C25%2C305%7C26%2C357%7C27%2C529%7C28
Host:website.co.uk
Origin:http://website.co.uk
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://website.co.uk/create-event/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data
userID:1
event-name:test event name
address-1:The Custard Factory
postcode:B9 4AA
address-2:
city:Birmingham
region:West Midlands
country:UK
lat:52.475514
long:-1.8842237999999725
phone:0121 285 5124
phone-alt:
email:info@b9media.co.uk
website:
event-main-cat:2
sub-cat:
suitable-for-ages:18-30

Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:183
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 09 Jul 2014 11:58:24 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=1000
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

**Response**

```
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_insert_post() in /home/lukeseag/public_html/codeplayground/woa/wp-content/themes/woa-2014/auto-save-post.php on line 30`
```

Comment: whats `$_POST['serialize']` for? and i dont see any kind of authentication here either - a public api that posts data seems like a bad idea

Comment: Can you add the Inspector log's of your ajax connection? to do this open WebKit's Inspector (Chrome/Safari/ any other web kit browser) in FF install & open Firebug, then this is the same for both open the networks tab then send your request and you should see the call to `/auto-save-post.php` open that and copy everything about the request into a code view will you it will help us see where your code is going wrong

Comment: I think your `url--->templateDir ` is not available in this iife scope.

Comment: Hi @Martin Barker, Just checked this out and in the response I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_insert_post() in /home/lukeseag/public_html/codeplayground/woa/wp-content/themes/woa-2014/auto-save-post.php on line 27` I'm guessing this is where the issue is?

Comment: Yeah Sorry i did not get back to you but you got the answer and glad i could help you get the answer though showing you how to get the debug/error from server side when making a XHR request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
require_once  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-load.php";
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting('E_ALL');

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post_title'] ),
  'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => $user_id,
  'tags_input'    => implode(",","TAG1,TAG2"),//$_POST['tags'] 
);

// Insert the post into the database
$post_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
echo $post_ID;
```

Comment: Just so it's clear, the main issue was because I wasn't doing `require_once  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-load.php";`, which meant this script didn't understand wordpress' built in functions.

Comment: Yes, when you going to use WP function, you always have to start with this line 
`requie_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-load.php";`